# match any part of a URL

Tags: php

Can anyone help me figure out how to search a URL and print a class based on its result for example:

http://www.?.com/garden-design.html

What i am trying to achieve is using a switch using PHP mathcing a term of  say "garden" after the first trailing slash then it would print a class.  If it matched construction it would print a different class.   There are only three so i know which words to search for.  This doesnt have to be dynamic.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it does not have to be dynamic, you could do it like this:

```
switch(true)
{
    case stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'garden'):
        return 'garden';
        break;
    case stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'construction'):
        return 'construction';
        break;
    default:
        return 'default';
        break;

}
```

The above is quite explicit. A more compact solution could be

```
function getCategory($categories)
{
    foreach($catgories as $category) {
        if stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $category) {
            return $category;
        }
    }
}

$categories = array('garden', 'construction', 'indoor');
echo getCategory($categories);
```

This will not give you the first *word* after `/`, but just check if one of your keywords exists in the requested URI and return it.

You could also use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to split the URI into it's components and work with String functions on the `path` component, e.g.

```
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
```

In `www.example.com/garden-design.html?foo=bar`, this would give you just the part `garden-design.html`. In your scenario you'd probably still do the stripos on it then, so you can just as well do it directly on the URL instead of parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a regular expression:

/http://www..+.com/(garden|construction|indoor)(-design)?.html/

then $1 would give you garden, construction or indoor as string.

you can also use `(.+)` to collect any string at that spot.

**Update** made "-design" optional.

Comment: it may not always have design...it may be just construction.html.  Will this make any difference?

Comment: See update, you can make a string optional by placing in `()?`

Answer (score 0):

I'd have thought that making use of `parse_url` would probably be a good starting point - you could then `explode` the path component and then do simply `strpos` comparisons against the three strings you're looking for, if a simple switch statement isn't sufficient. (Be sure to check for !== false if you go down the strpos route.)

This would **potentially** be faster than a regex based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the php function [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos).  With it you could do something like:

```
$url  = "http://www.nothing.com/garden-design.html";
if (strpos($url, "/garden-design.html"))
    doSomething();
else if (strpos($url, "/construction-design.html"))
    doSomethingElse();
else if (strpos($url, "/indoor-design.html"))
    doSomethingElseInstead();
```

String matching is generally quicker and more efficient than regular expressions.